# Pass value of <select> via url on form submit

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple form that I want to pass the user selection via url.

```
<form method="GET" action="course-registration.asp">
<select>
 <option value="#">--Select--</option>
 <option value="courseOfferings[special_1005][item_1]=January%2030-31,%202014&course=ArcCHECK / 3DVH Product Training&date=January 30-31, 2013&description=This hands-on product training course focuses on the use of the ArcCHECK 3-dimensional beam dosimetry QA system with 3DVH software.">January 30-31, 2014</option>                 
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I alert the value of the select, it shows correctly, but it does not pass to the url when button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a name to the select element

like `<select name="dept">`

```
<form method="GET" action="course-registration.asp">
   <select name="something">
     <option value="#">--Select--</option>
     <option value="cof">January 30-31, 2014</option>                 
  </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

this will make your url lookblike "http://some.co/?something=manything"